# Error while importing Snackbar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-snackbar

I am trying to import Snackbar using below command. But getting error `Cannot Resolve symbol Snackbar`. What is the possible issue here? I tried adding "android.support.design" dependency but didn't work.

```
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar
```

My build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.anamika.anamika"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.9.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**`Snackbar`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar) **belongs to Maven artifact `com.android.support:design:27.1.1`**

You need to add dependency of design library

add below dependency in your **build.gradle**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

Than **`Clean - Re-Build - Run`** your project

> If you are migrating to androidx then use

`com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text`

instead of

`android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text`

Don't miss to import `import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;`

Also implement `implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02"`

Comment: Should be implementation rather than compile these days.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing dependency for design library in your `build.gralde`. Update it as follows:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    ...
}
```

After updating the file, click `Sync Now` at top right corner. Ensure you have internet connection so that dependencies can be downloaded.

If you still face issues after that, then clean and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 1):

designYou need to add in `dependencies` in your `build.gradle` file.

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

And `Sync` your project.

Answer (score 0):

I got error when I tried to import the `Snackbar` library

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

and I received new error saying that the support library should be the same version as the compileSDKVersion version, so I changed the implementation to

```
implementation  'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

it fixed the error and I was able to use the `Snackbar`.